# Vim normal! sending literal <Space> string instead of whitespace character

Tags: vim

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
:normal! I###<Space><Esc>
```

The end result I want when I execute this command over a word is this:

```
### word
```

But instead I get this:

```
###<Space>word
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim's `:normal` is a nightmare with anything moderately complicated. I don't remember why, but this is the easiest way to get what you want. You need to escape the opening < in a string passed to execute.

```
execute "normal! I###\<Space>\<Esc>"
```

Edit: Vim doesn't really explain why, but `:help normal`

```
        An alternative is to use |:execute|, which uses an
        expression as argument.  This allows the use of
        printable characters to represent special characters.
```

Answer (score 5):

Lets first explain the vim command:

- `:normal!` run the rest of the commands as normal mode
- `I` enter insert mode from the beginning of the line `<shift> + i`
- `###<Space><Esc>` - type out the characters `###<Space><Esc>` literally since we are in insert mode (notice that if you just enter insert mode, and type `###<space><esc>`, you'll get just that literally.)

When this command finishes, you'll notice how it's still in normal mode. This means that your command can just omit the `<space><esc>` and enter the space literally:

```
:norm! I###
```

(There is an extra space after the last hash)